# Create Multiple Python dictionaries from CSV using same column as key

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv:

```
Col1, Col2,   Col3, ...  
10,   0.024,  0.0012, ...  
20,   0.0013, 0.43, ...
```

I want a list of dictionaries like so
`[{"Col1":"Col2"}, {"Col1": "Col3"},...]`
with `Col1` always as the key for each dictionary

I've tried this and it works for the first dictionary, but produces empty 
dictionaries for all the others.

```
import os, csv
path = r"I:\ARC\WIP\KevinWIP\Risk\Data\PythonGui"
os.chdir(path)
with open('DispersalKernal10m.csv', mode = 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    DistProb_LUT = [
    {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader},
    {rows[0]:rows[2] for rows in reader},
    {rows[0]:rows[3] for rows in reader},
    {rows[0]:rows[4] for rows in reader},
    {rows[0]:rows[5] for rows in reader},
    {rows[0]:rows[6] for rows in reader},
    {rows[0]:rows[7] for rows in reader}]
    infile.close()

print(DistProb_LUT)
```

Searched around and everything I tried didn't work. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You can only iterate over `reader` **once**, then you're at the end of the `infile`...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reading a file is typically not an operation that you can repeat many times in a row without reopening the file.  Therefore, something like this may be of use to you:

```
import os, csv
path = r'I:\ARC\WIP\KevinWIP\Risk\Data\PythonGui'
os.chdir(path)
DistProb_LUT = [{} for i in range(7)]
with open('DispersalKernal10m.csv', mode = 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        DistProb_LUT[0][row[0]] = row[1]
        DistProb_LUT[1][row[0]] = row[2]
        DistProb_LUT[2][row[0]] = row[3]
        DistProb_LUT[3][row[0]] = row[4]
        DistProb_LUT[4][row[0]] = row[5]
        DistProb_LUT[5][row[0]] = row[6]
        DistProb_LUT[6][row[0]] = row[7]

print(DistProb_LUT)
```

Also, you don't need the `infile.close()` line.  The `with` statement takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

For creating the first dictionary itself, you are looping through the entire file and reaching the end of file, so for all other dictionaries your file cursor is always at end and hence all other dictionaries are empty. Instead of doing dictionary comprehension like that, use a for loop outside the dictionary creation portion and change the logic a little bit, like below -

```
import os, csv
path = r'I:\ARC\WIP\KevinWIP\Risk\Data\PythonGui'
os.chdir(path)
DistProb_LUT = [{} for _ in range(7)]
with open('DispersalKernal10m.csv', mode = 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for rows in reader:
        for i in range(7):
            DistProb_LUT[i][rows[0]] = rows[i+1]
```

You also do not need to close the infile as it would be automatically closed by `with` statement.